# MASM: Force OFFSET directive not to be relocated

Tags: assembly, dos, masm

I'm writing a multi-modular assembly project with MASM for DOS. In particular, I'm trying to do a very simple DOS-like OS,

I have several segments defined like this;

```
fileseg segment byte public 'code'
fileseg ends

memseg segment byte public 'code'
memseg ends

diskseg segment byte public 'code'
diskseg ends

bootseg segment byte public 'code'
bootseg ends
```

As you see all of them are byte-aligned (design decision). Also I have a cseg group that encompasses all of the above segments

```
cseg group fileseg, memseg, diskseg, bootseg, ...
```

so when I want to reference a public label, no matter if it's defined in a different segment, i will do something like:

```
assume ds:cseg, es:cseg, ss:cseg

mov   si, offset label_in_this_segment
mov   bx, offset label_in_another_segment
```

and it'll get the 'global' offset within cseg, which is right. But the problem arises when you write some code that needs to be executed in a fixed location, as a boot sector, that executes at 0000:7C00h (in my case at 07C0:0)

so I wrote it like this:

```
bootseg segment byte public 'code'

; Want all data references to be relative to this segment, not CSEG
assume ds:bootseg

boot_start::

    jmp     start

    boot_data   t_bootloader_data <>        

start:

    ; make IP point to 0000h
    mov     ax, 07C0h
    push    ax
    mov     ax, offset ds:real_start ; "BAD" offset
    push    ax
    retf
real_start:        
    mov     ax, cs
    mov     ds, ax
    ...
```

I put "BAD" in quotes because MASM is actually doing it right, since bootseg is also part of the `cseg` group (because `boot_data` it's referenced from some other segments), so the linker marks "real_start" as relocatable.

So the question would be: how do I tell the assembler that I want`real_start` to be offseted from `bootseg` itself?

I tried some tricks that work, like making `bootseg` be the first segment defined, or making it paragraph-aligned, but these seem somewhat hacky to me.

I also tried to put `bootseg` out of the cseg group but again, I need `boot_data` to be referenced from other segments before the boot sector is written to disk.

Comment: The problem: the bootseg has two values: at boot, and after long jump. You could do a offset difference. (which is valid and the same on both cs) and use such value.

Comment: Don't try to get MASM to understand the offset.  Maybe do something like `jmp 07C0h:(real_start - start)` if that's the right syntax (instead of that push/push / retf stuff.  IDK why you using AX for that if you're not going to take advantage of the value still in AX after reaching `real_start`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes It's compiled for .286 so can't neither write jmp XXXX:XXXX nor push immediate values.

Comment: @Trap The 80286 most definitely has the `jmp far ptr16:16` instruction.  Yes, you can use it.

Comment: [`push imm8/16` is 186](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdocb.html).  `jmp ptr16:16` is baseline 8086 according to the same doc.

Comment: @PeterCordes You're right, you can do push imm. However, despite jmp xxxx:xxxx is a valid instruction, MASM doesn't seem to like it. I always have to write some kind of workaround, like inlining a db 0EAh, followed by a couple of dw's for seg:off, in which case, I prefer to do the push/push/retf stuff

Comment: Maybe check the manual and find out the syntax;  Maybe they want `jmp far something:something`, or maybe there's a different syntax altogether.

Comment: Without looking too closely at your question if it solves your actual problem, the direct answer is use `OFFSET bootseg:real_start`. As for how to get MASM to generate a far jump to specific fixed segment and offset see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706833/how-to-code-a-far-absolute-jmp-call-instruction-in-masm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify what segment you want OFFSET to be relative by prefixing the symbol with `segment:`. For example:

```
     mov     ax, offset bootseg:real_start
```

However this doesn't work because you're using BYTE alignment, so the there's two different starting address for the segment.  In real mode segments have to be paragraph (16-byte) aligned, so linker rounds down the start `bootseg` to the nearest paragraph boundary, and then adjusts any offsets to be relative to the new starting address.  Since when the bootseg is actually loaded and executes it does actually start a paragraph boundry this means all the adjusted offsets are incorrect.

Note that is isn't limited to just the OFFSET directive, but also any absolute references `bootseg` makes to addresses within `bootseg`.  You should really consider making `bootseg` PARA aligned.

If you still want to use byte alignment you'll need to calculate the offset yourself:

```
     mov     ax, real_start - boot_start
```

Note that since you're targeting 80286 processors, you can do this instead:

```
     push    real_start - boot_start
```

The PUSH immediate instruction was introduced to the x86 architecture with the 80186.

If you have absolute references like this within `bootseg`:

```
mov  al, [boot_data.foo]
```

You'll need to change it to something like this for the offset to be correct when the boot sector is executed:

```
mov  al, BYTE PTR ds:[boot_data.foo - boot_start]
```

Finally you can avoid the whole PUSH/RETF nonsense and code [an absolute far JMP to a fixed segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706833/how-to-code-a-far-absolute-jmp-call-instruction-in-masm) directly in MASM like this:

```
bootseg segment byte public 'code'

assume ds:bootseg

boot_start::

    jmp     start

    ; ...

start:

    jmp     real_start_abs
real_start:        
    mov     ax, cs
    mov     ds, ax

    ; ...

bootseg ENDS

bootseg_abs SEGMENT USE16 AT 07c0h
    ORG      (real_start - boot_start)
real_start_abs LABEL FAR
bootseg_abs ENDS
```

Comment: The segment prefix 'bootseg' does the same than 'assume ds:bootseg' and then ds:xxx_label. Tried both and neither of them worked (yields the same "invalid" offset)

Comment: The problem has to do with bootseg being part of a byte-aligned segment group.