# Producing bootloader.bin file using "masm bootloader.asm", error "must be in segment block"

Tags: assembly, masm, bootloader

i want to compile a **boot sector code** from bootloader.asm to bootloader.bin using masm. But it is throwing error "**must be in segment block**". can't we use segmentation in boot loader code if not then what is the solution for the error "must be in segment block".

I am using following command to compile boot loader code:

```
MASM myboot.asm
```

after which i can use LINK to generate bin file.

My boot sector code is as given below:

```
                   JMP     START
                   NOP                                        

bsOEM_NAME            DB      'MSDOS5.0'      ;  8 bytes
bsBYTES_PER_SECTOR    DW      ?
bsSECTORS_PER_CLUSTER DB      ?
bsRESERVED_SECTORS    DW      ?
bsFAT_COPIES          DB      ?
bsROOT_DIR_ENTRIES    DW      ?
bsTOTAL_DISK_SECTORS  DW      ?
bsMEDIA_DESCRIPTOR    DB      ?
bsSECTORS_PER_FAT     DW      ?
bsSECTORS_PER_TRACK   DW      ?
bsSIDES               DW      ?
bsHIDDEN_SECTORS_HIGH DW      ?
bsHIDDEN_SECTORS_LOW  DW      ?
bsTOTAL_NUM_SECTORS   DD      ?
bsPHYS_DRIVE_NUMBER_1 DB      ?
bsPHYS_DRIVE_NUMBER_2 DB      ?
bsBOOT_RECORD_SIG     DB      29h
bsVOL_SERIAL_NUM      DD      1F61A800h
bsVOLUME_LABEL        DB      'NO NAME    '   ; 11 bytes
bsFILE_SYSTEM_ID      DB      'FAT16   '      ;  8 bytes

;Disk Parameter Block

;   The DPB is located in the ROM BIOS at the address pointed to 
;by 0078h.
;   The 11 bytes starting from START are overwritten at COPY_DPB 
;with the
;   DPB (7C3E-7C48).  This is what the area looks like *after* 
;the copy
;   at COPY_DPB:
; 

START               CLI                  ; Disable interrupts
                XOR        AX,AX     ; AX=0000
                MOV        SS,AX     ; SS=0000
                MOV        SP,7C00   ; SP grows in decrements
                PUSH       SS                                 
                POP        ES        ; ES=0000
                MOV        BX,0078   ; The address of the ROM
                                     ; BIOS disk table is 78h.
                                     ; (INT 18h).  ROM routine
                                    ; copies this address during
                                     ; cold boot initialization.
                                                           
                LDS        SI,[BX]  ; SI points to ROMBIOS table
                                    ; The source for the copy
                PUSH       DS                                 
                PUSH       SI                                 
                PUSH       SS                                 
                PUSH       BX                                 
                MOV        DI,START  ; Address of destination
                MOV        CX,000B   ; Size of area to copy
                                          ; (Disk parameters)
                CLD                  ; Set direction flag to inc
                REPZ                 ; Move 11 bytes from the
                                     ; disk parameter area to
                                     ; overlap with the start
                                          ; of the code at 7D3E
                                          ; (save space?)
                MOVSB                                         

                PUSH       ES                                 
                POP        DS        ; DS=0000
                MOV        BYTE PTR [DI-02],0F
                                     ; At this point, DI points
                                     ; to 7C49, one byte after
                                     ; the last thing copied.
                                     ; Destination operand is
                                     ; dpbHEAD_SETTLE_TIME.
                MOV        CX,bsSECTORS_PER_TRACK
                MOV        [DI-07],CL ; Destination operand is
                                      ; dpbSECTORS_PER_TRACK.
                MOV        [BX+02],AX ; Destination operand is
                                           ; dpbMOTOR_OFF_DELAY.
                MOV        WORD PTR [BX],START
                STI                  ; The code at 7C6B installs
                                     ; the new Int 1E into the
                                     ; interrupt table at
                                     ; 0000:0078. At 7C68, AX is
                                     ; 0. START is the offset
                                     ; for the new INT 1E.
                INT        13        ; Reset drives (AX=0000)
                JB         ERROR_IN_BOOT_1
                XOR        AX,AX                              
                CMP        bsTOTAL_DISK_SECTORS,AX
                JZ         LOOP_1

                MOV        CX,bsTOTAL_DISK_SECTORS
                MOV        bsTOTAL_NUM_SECTORS,CX
LOOP_1          MOV        AL,bsFAT_COPIES       
                MUL        WORD PTR bsSECTORS_PER_FAT
                ADD        AX,bsHIDDEN_SECTORS_HIGH
                ADC        DX,bsHIDDEN_SECTORS_LOW
                ADD        AX,bsRESERVED_SECTORS
                ADC        DX,+00                             
                MOV        [7C50],AX                          
                MOV        [7C52],DX                          
                MOV        [7C49],AX                          
                MOV        [7C4B],DX                          
                MOV        AX,0020                            
                MUL        WORD PTR bsROOT_DIR_ENTRIES
                MOV        BX,bsBYTES_PER_SECTOR
                ADD        AX,BX                              
                DEC        AX                                 
                DIV        BX                                 
                ADD        [7C49],AX                          
                ADC        WORD PTR [7C4B],+00                
                MOV        BX,0500   ; Buffer for root directory
                MOV        DX,[7C4B]                          
                MOV        AX,[7C49]                          
                CALL       CALCULATE

                JB         ERROR_IN_BOOT_1                    
                MOV        AL,01                              
                CALL       READ_SECTOR
                JB         ERROR_IN_BOOT_1 ;Error? Print message
                                            ; and reboot.
                MOV        DI,BX
                MOV        SI,OFFSET FILE_IO_SYS
                REPZ
                CMPSB
                JNZ        ERROR_IN_BOOT_1 ;First file in root
                                           ; dir is not IO.SYS?
                                                ; Print error.
                LEA        DI,[BX+20]                         
                MOV        CX,000B      ; 11 characters in DOS
                                             ; filename.
                REPZ                                          
                CMPSB                 ; Is second file in root
                                           ; MSDOS.SYS?
                JZ         LOOP_2     ; Yes?  Then continue on.
ERROR_IN_BOOT_1     MOV        SI,OFFSET NON_SYSTEM_DISK
                CALL       WRITE_STRING
                XOR        AX,AX       
                INT        16          
                POP        SI          
                POP        DS          
                POP        [SI]        
                POP        [SI+02]                            
                INT        19                                 

ERROR_IN_BOOT_2 POP        AX                                 
                POP        AX                                 
                POP        AX                                 
                JMP        ERROR_IN_BOOT_1
LOOP_2          MOV        AX,[BX+1A]                         
                DEC        AX                                 
                DEC        AX                                 
                MOV        BL,SECTORS_PER_CLUSTER
                XOR        BH,BH                              
                MUL        BX                                 
                ADD        AX,[7C49]                          
                ADC        DX,[7C4B]                          
                MOV        BX,0700      ; DOS loading buffer
                MOV        CX,0003                            
LOOP_3          PUSH       AX                                 
                PUSH       DX                                 
                PUSH       CX                                 
                CALL       CALCULATE      
                JB         ERROR_IN_BOOT_2
                MOV        AL,01          
                CALL       READ_SECTOR    
                POP        CX             
                POP        DX             
                POP        AX                                 
                JB         ERROR_IN_BOOT_1
                ADD        AX,0001                            
                ADC        DX,+00                             
                ADD        BX,BYTES_PER_SEC
                LOOP       LOOP_3                               
                MOV        CH,MEDIA_DESCRIPTOR
                MOV        DL,PHYS_DRIVE_NUMBER_1
                MOV        BX,[7C49]                          
                MOV        AX,[7C4B]                          
                JMP        0070:0000    ; Transfer to ROM BIOS

 WRITE_STRING   LODSB                                         
                OR         AL,AL                              
                JZ         RETURN_FROM_2
                MOV        AH,0E       
                MOV        BX,0007     
                INT        10          
                JMP        WRITE_STRING

CALCULATE       CMP        DX,SECTORS_PER_TRACK
                JNB        RETURN_FROM_1
                DIV        WORD PTR SECTORS_PER_TRACK
                INC        DL                                 
                MOV        [7C4F],DL                          
                XOR        DX,DX                              
                DIV        WORD PTR SIDES
                MOV        PHYS_DRIVE_NUMBER_2,DL
                MOV        [7C4D],AX                          
                CLC                                           
                RET                                           

RETURN_FROM_1       STC                                           
RETURN_FROM_2       RET                                           

READ_SECTOR         MOV        AH,02      ; 02h is ReadSector .
                MOV        DX,[7C4D]  ; DH is head/side number.
                                        ; DL is drive number.
                                      ; (Bit 7 of DL set for HD)
                MOV        CL,06      ; CL is sector number.
                SHL        DH,CL      ; Multiply DH (number of
                                           ; heads) by 6.
                OR         DH,[7C4F]
                MOV        CX,DX
                XCHG       CH,CL
                MOV        DL,bsPHYS_DRIVE_NUMBER_1
                MOV        DH,bsPHYS_DRIVE_NUMBER_2
                INT        13           ; ReadSector
                RET

NON_SYSTEM_DISK     DB      13,10
                DB      'Non-System disk or disk error'
                DB      13,10
                DB      'Replace and press any key when ready'
                DB      13,10,0
FILE_IO_SYS         DB      'IO      SYS'
FILE_MSDOS_SYS      DB      'MSDOS   SYS'
                DB      0,0,55,AA
```

Comment: If you are using MASM 6.15 or higher I'd use `.model tiny` `.code` at the top and `end` at the bottom of the file. Everything into the simplified code section called `.code`. But that wont solve all your problems. One big one is that it seems like this code was intended to be used by debug.exe/debug.com or some very antiquated assembler given that you don't use a `h` prefix to denote hexadecimal numbers. Every hex number in your code is being treated as decimal by MASM and it will throw errors on most of them.

Comment: Michael you are right, compiler is generating errors on every occurrences of [memory address] (e.g. MOV [7C50], AX) by mentioning "nondigit in number",AS "C" is not a digit in "7C50", but when i add "h" for example (MOV [7C50h],AX), then it is throwing another error by mentioning "immediate operand not allowed", As obviously [7C50h] is an immediate operand. what is the solution please explain.

Comment: Because you aren't using labels to data items you will need to override with DS using something like `MOV ds:[7C50h], AX`. This is a peculiarity with MASM and compatible assemblers.

Comment: thanks Michael your answer help me alot but still my code is producing an error by mentioning "segment, group, or segment register expected" at line "JMP   0070:0000h"  ; Transfer to ROM BIOS

Comment: MASM doesn't support encoding FAR JMP directly like that. You could try replacing the JMP with: `db 0eah` `dw 0000h, 0070h`

Comment: thanks Michael, i still have confusion, you means that we will declare two variables one is for "db 0eah" and another one for "dw 0000h,0070h". is it so. then what should i do to access memory location 0070:0000h. please explain    in little more detail that how should i code this.

Comment: i will be thankful if you write code lines to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Replace `JMP 0070h:0000h` with 2 lines. `db 0eah` followed by  `dw 0000h, 0070h` , This manually encodes a FAR JMP. byte 0eah is the instruction opcode for a FAR JMP. The word after that is the offset portion of the jmp instruction and the word after that is the segment.

Comment: Other way of doing it that are more involved can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32707007/3857942

Comment: I have the bootloader code given above. How can I run this to get ms dos run. That is i can found drive letter A:\>